# Joomla Breezing forms - Form not found issue

Tags: joomla, breezingforms

I am a newbie in Joomla. I have a site with Breezingforms installed.
Last week we created a form with 2 pages and around 25 elements. The form was published to the front end and was working without any issues.
Last day when i opened the site the form link is broken

I am getting the message

> [Form 8 not found!]

instead of displaying the form elements. In admin am still able to see all form and page elements.

I also found that the forms generated are not saved. When i click any other tab and later when i come back I see all forms disappeared.

Am using Joomla 3.4 and Breezingforms build 906.

Any help is appreciated.

thank you

Answer (score 1):

Hi to solve this issue simply click on the three save buttons that are available on breezing form whenever you are working on a form. One exists at the bottom left corner, one at the center left and the other at the top left corner. After working on any page, section or element click the three save buttons before you move to the next page, section or element.

Answer (score 0):

1. I would urge you to follow the other advice.  **Make sure you click on save in both places**.  One is on your form and one is in the top left of the browser (on desktop).

Once you have done that your form should be saved, but there is one other possibility for why you cannot see it.

2. When you go into Breezing forms and click on "forms".  You might see an empty page.  If you **choose the dropdown and choose "quickforms"** you will see some forms that were not previously displayed.
3. If you are receiving an error "Form 8 not found" you should check the spelling of the form name.  Don't forget you have a **form name** and a **form title**.  You need to **make sure you use the form name** (which you can change).  I usually copy and paste it.  **Form names would contain a space**, so I would expect it to be the generated form name by Breezing forms.  You should change it to "Form8" or "Form-8" to make it work properly.